# Encrypt a file in python-gnupg using multiple keys

Tags: python, gnupg

I am encrypting a file using python-gnupg and it looks like encrypt_file onlys accepts a single key for the sign parameter.  If I have a key file with multiple keys that I want to encrypt the document with, how can I do this?  If I understand correctly I should be able to encrypt a file using multiple keys.

Comment: What exactly are you aiming at getting back from gpg? Do you want a single output document that can be decrypted by any of the keys, or do you want several separate outputs, one encrypted to each of the keys (or, I suppose a single document that requires all the keys to be decrypted)?

Answer (score 0):

Having re-read your question again after reading the python-gnupg documentation, I think you're asking about signing a document with several private keys at the same time you are encrypting it.

Unfortunately, that process is not supported by python-gnupg, because GnuPG does not support it either. You'll have to decide how exactly you want your signatures to be applied, then do them one at a time.

You can, for instance layer the signatures, by encrypting and signing with one key, then signing the results with another private key (and repeating for any additional keys you have beyond the second).

Alternatively, you could create several "detached" signatures, each of just the base document (so no signatures would be applied to other signatures). This is a bit more complicated, as I'm not sure that there's any file format that will automatically be recognized by GnuPG to verify several detached signatures at once.

Answer (score 0):

In python-gnupg encrypt_file actually accepts a list (the documentation refers to it as an array) for the recipients.  This should work:

```
import gnupg

gpg_home = "~/.gnupg"
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=gpg_home)

data = raw_input("Enter full path of file to encrypt: ")
rkeys = raw_input("Enter key IDs separated by spaces: ")
savefile = data+".asc"

afile = open(data, "rb")
gpg.encrypt_file(afile, rkeys.split(), always_trust=True, output=savefile)
afile.close()
```

It's pretty crude in that it will write the ciphertext to the same directory as the plaintext, but it will work.  Note the rkeys.split() option, that's what turns the string of key IDs or UIDs separated by spaces into the Python list.